# How to hide UL only when clicked outside of to DOCUMENT?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm not sure why I'm getting this wrong, and every time I try to compare the target, I get undefined.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
menu.find('> li').each(function() {
    var li = $(this);
    var ul = li.find('> ul');
    var a = li.find('> a');

    if(ul.length) {
        a.click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();

            if(a.hasClass('open')) {
                a.removeClass('open');
            }
            else {
                a.addClass('open');
            }

            ul.toggle();

            $(document).click(function() {
                var target = $(event.target);

                alert(target.attr('class'));

                if(!target.is(ul) && !target.is(li) && !target.is(a)) {
                    ul.hide();
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: LOL 'undefined', sorry.

Comment: Couple observations: You're adding another click handler to document for each found anchor? And did you intend for the document click handler to use the `event` from the parent scope? I'm confused about what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

I found several mistakes in your code:

- First of all move the `$(document).click()` event outside the each loop. Otherwise this event will be attached multiple times based on how many `menu>li` you have on your page.
- Second of all and probably the reason you're getting `undefined` on your `alert(target.attr('class'));` call is that you don't provide a parameter for your click event. Change your code to:

`$(document).click(function (event) {});`